# Arithmetic equations query in PHP / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm not too much of an expert in Maths but when we try to equate `19.95 / 2.85` in any calculator we get the output as 7.

Trying the same arithmetic equation in PHP:

```
$val = 19.95 / 2.85;
echo $val; // 7
echo floor($val); // 6
```

Trying the same arithmetic equation in JavaScript:

```
var val = 19.95 / 2.85;
console.log(val); // 6.999999999999999
console.log(Math.floor(val)); // 6
```

How can I make sure that when i use `floor()` in PHP that the output I get from the above arithmetic equation equals 7?

Comment: This is a known issue in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: ok... but what's wrong with the PHP code then?

Comment: @EricPPereira Nothing? The result is simply beyond the number of significant decimals that PHP displays, so it rounds up to 7, unless specifically told to round down.

Comment: @EricPPereira If you want more precision you can try using build in php libraries like BCMath [divide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php). You can set the default scale with [bcscale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php)

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgenseni Thanks. Will give this a look.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get near a value of number 
ex:

6.5 the near natural integer of is 7

6.4 the near natural integer of is 6

You can to that with javascript with `Math.round`

```
var val = 19.95 / 2.85;
console.log(val); // 6.999999999999999
console.log(Math.round(val)); // 7
```